# div class "in" h2 class possible?

Tags: php, html, css

Full Code:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"<?php post_class(); ?>><h2 class="TITLE"><a href="     <?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'TXv2' ),      the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><div      class="BUBBLE"><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%'); ?></div></h2>
```

My Problem:

```
<h2 class="TITLE">PHP_CODE<div class="BUBBLE">PHP_CONTENT</div></h2>
```

My CSS looks for the "div/BUBBLE":

```
.BUBBLE { color: #FFF; }
```

And for the h2/TITLE:

```
.TITLE { color: #000; }
```

TITLE is right, but the "BUBBLE"-Font is black, too.
Is it possible to change the CSS-Format within a h2 Tag?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
.TITLE .BUBBLE {color: #fff;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3vj8q/ (black background added to make text viewable).

Some information about how specificity works: http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/inheritance_and_cascade

Comment: In the Demo its works: http://jsfiddle.net/3vj8q/4/ but not on my website? The title has some more code: `#content .TITLE { color: #222; font-size: 26px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.3em; margin-bottom: 5px; }
.entry-title a:link, .entry-title a:visited { color: #111; text-decoration: none; }
.TITLE a:active, .TITLE a:hover { color: #666; }` (thats ALL of them)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use text tags for text formatting :

```
<h2 class="TITLE">PHP_CODE<span class="BUBBLE">PHP_CONTENT</span></h2>
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zgU4N/)